# google visualization filtering by string(name,company...etc) ERROR in view

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I would like to make a filter by company.
However, all the Strings from my database values are NaN [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaZs3.png)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', { packages : ['controls'] } );

function createTable() {

          // JSON request
          var jsonData = $.ajax({

            url: 'http://getdata',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json'

          }).done(function (results) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();           
            data.addColumn('date',   'Performance_date');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Performance_company');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Performance_zone');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Entradas');

            $.each(results, function (i, row) {
              data.addRow([new Date((row.performance_date)),parseInt(row.performance_company),parseInt(row.performance_zone),parseInt(row.performance_profit)]);
            });




     // Define category pickers for 'Companies'
    var myFields = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
                'containerId': 'company_div',
                'options': {
                    'filterColumnLabel': 'Performance_company',
                    'ui': {
                        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                        'allowTyping': false,
                        'allowMultiple': false
                    }

                }


            });
```

Comment: Please add a sample of the data (results)

Comment: Hello, data json return results here https://jsfiddle.net/kimoudev/63vgmdb6/ thank you for your help